# All possible combinations of elements in a list which are next to each other

Tags: python, list

I need a function which allows me to generate all possible combinations of elements in a list but only if they are next to each other in the original list:

```
stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        print(subset)

#Output: 
()
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(4,)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4)

# Desired Output:
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(4,)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Can I ask why you need this? Are you doing something for statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def get_combos(d, c = []):
   yield tuple(c)
   if d:
      yield from get_combos(d[1:], c+[d[0]])
      yield from get_combos(d[1:], [d[0]])

result = set(filter(None, get_combos(stuff)))
```

Output:

```
{(1,), 
 (2,), 
 (3,), 
 (4,), 
 (1, 2), 
 (2, 3), 
 (3, 4), 
 (1, 2, 3), 
 (2, 3, 4), 
 (1, 2, 3, 4)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stuffsets = [stuff[i:j] for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(stuff)+1), 2)]
```

Comment: Almost. The full list will be missing from this though.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the problem as getting all of the possible slices within `stuff`:

```
>>> sorted(itertools.chain(
...     stuff[i:j] for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(stuff)+1), 2)
... ), key=len)
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

`itertools.combinations(range(len(stuff)+1), 2)` produces `i,j` pairs where `i` ranges from 0 to 3 and `j` ranges from 1 to 4; getting all combinations of those values produces all possible slices of the 4-element list.  The sort on `key=len` produces the ordering you asked for, but if ordering isn't important you can leave that off.